# Can feats like Psionic Weapon, Shot or Fist work with out interference with Path of War Rules?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, psionics, path-of-war

Can feats like [Psionic Weapon](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/feats/psionic-weapon-psionic/), [Shot](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/feats/psionic-shot-psionic/) or [Fist](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/feats/psionic-fist-psionic/); or [Greater Psionic Weapon](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/feats/greater-psionic-weapon-psionic/), [Shot](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/feats/greater-psionic-shot-psionic/) or [Fist](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/feats/greater-psionic-fist-psionic/) work without interference or sacrifice with [Path of War](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/path-of-war/) Rules?

Effects from stances remain so long as stance is not changed. Gaining and using focus* during a rotation of Boosts, Counters and Strikes is what I worry about. With [Psionic Meditation](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/feats/psionic-meditation-psionic/) you can gain focus with a move action, but can I expend/use said focus at anytime during when a boost, strike or counter happens?

---

* see the "[Gain psionic focus](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/feats/)" part for the rules

Answer (score 3):

The feats you list can be extended in any attack, at no extra action cost. Their damage boosts are untyped and so stack with anything except each with itself (so even with two psionic foci, you cannot use any twice on one attack). The only conflict they have with Path of War, or anything else, is the actions needed to regain focus. Even with Psionic Meditation, focusing takes a move action which means pretty much every action is accounted for, so enemies better not do things like not stand next to you.